# Seeking an appropriate Ruby/Python parser generator

Tags: python, ruby, debugging, parser-generator

The first parser generator I've worked with was Parse::RecDescent, and the guides/tutorials available for it were great, but the most useful feature it has was it's debugging tools, specifically the **tracing** capabilities ( activated by setting $RD_TRACE to 1 ). I am looking for a parser generator that can help you debug it's rules.

The thing is, it has to be written in Python or in Ruby, and have a verbose mode/trace mode or very helpful debugging techniques.

Does anyone know such a parser generator ?

### Edit

When I said debugging, I wasn't referring to debugging Python or Ruby. I was referring to debugging the parser generator, see what it's doing at every step, see every char it's reading, rules it's trying to match.

### Edit

I am seeking a parser generator framework, and an illustration of some of its debugging features. I'm not interested in pdb, but in parser's debugging framework. Also, please don't mention treetop. I'm not interested in it.

Comment: hey! and what about ruby ones? :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python is a pretty easy language to debug. You can just do import pdb pdb.settrace().

However, these parser generators supposedly come with good debugging facilities.

http://www.antlr.org/

http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/

http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/

**In response to bounty**

Here is PLY debugging in action.

Source Code

```
tokens = (
    'NAME','NUMBER',
    )

literals = ['=','+','-','*','/', '(',')']

# Tokens

t_NAME    = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t

t_ignore = " \t"

def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count("\n")

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

# Build the lexer
import ply.lex as lex
lex.lex(debug=1)

# Parsing rules

precedence = (
    ('left','+','-'),
    ('left','*','/'),
    ('right','UMINUS'),
    )

# dictionary of names
names = { }

def p_statement_assign(p):
    'statement : NAME "=" expression'
    names[p[1]] = p[3]

def p_statement_expr(p):
    'statement : expression'
    print(p[1])

def p_expression_binop(p):
    '''expression : expression '+' expression
                  | expression '-' expression
                  | expression '*' expression
                  | expression '/' expression'''
    if p[2] == '+'  : p[0] = p[1] + p[3]
    elif p[2] == '-': p[0] = p[1] - p[3]
    elif p[2] == '*': p[0] = p[1] * p[3]
    elif p[2] == '/': p[0] = p[1] / p[3]

def p_expression_uminus(p):
    "expression : '-' expression %prec UMINUS"
    p[0] = -p[2]

def p_expression_group(p):
    "expression : '(' expression ')'"
    p[0] = p[2]

def p_expression_number(p):
    "expression : NUMBER"
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_expression_name(p):
    "expression : NAME"
    try:
        p[0] = names[p[1]]
    except LookupError:
        print("Undefined name '%s'" % p[1])
        p[0] = 0

def p_error(p):
    if p:
        print("Syntax error at '%s'" % p.value)
    else:
        print("Syntax error at EOF")

import ply.yacc as yacc
yacc.yacc()

import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    filename="parselog.txt"
)

while 1:
    try:
        s = raw_input('calc > ')
    except EOFError:
        break
    if not s: continue
    yacc.parse(s, debug=1)
```

Output

```
lex: tokens   = ('NAME', 'NUMBER')
lex: literals = ['=', '+', '-', '*', '/', '(', ')']
lex: states   = {'INITIAL': 'inclusive'}
lex: Adding rule t_NUMBER -> '\d+' (state 'INITIAL')
lex: Adding rule t_newline -> '\n+' (state 'INITIAL')
lex: Adding rule t_NAME -> '[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*' (state 'INITIAL')
lex: ==== MASTER REGEXS FOLLOW ====
lex: state 'INITIAL' : regex[0] = '(?P<t_NUMBER>\d+)|(?P<t_newline>\n+)|(?P<t_NAME>[a-zA-Z
_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)'
calc > 2+3
PLY: PARSE DEBUG START

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(NUMBER,2,1,0)
Action : Shift and goto state 3

State  : 3
Stack  : NUMBER . LexToken(+,'+',1,1)
Action : Reduce rule [expression -> NUMBER] with [2] and goto state 9
Result : <int @ 0x1a1896c> (2)

State  : 6
Stack  : expression . LexToken(+,'+',1,1)
Action : Shift and goto state 12

State  : 12
Stack  : expression + . LexToken(NUMBER,3,1,2)
Action : Shift and goto state 3

State  : 3
Stack  : expression + NUMBER . $end
Action : Reduce rule [expression -> NUMBER] with [3] and goto state 9
Result : <int @ 0x1a18960> (3)

State  : 18
Stack  : expression + expression . $end
Action : Reduce rule [expression -> expression + expression] with [2,'+',3] and goto state
 3
Result : <int @ 0x1a18948> (5)

State  : 6
Stack  : expression . $end
Action : Reduce rule [statement -> expression] with [5] and goto state 2
5
Result : <NoneType @ 0x1e1ccef4> (None)

State  : 4
Stack  : statement . $end
Done   : Returning <NoneType @ 0x1e1ccef4> (None)
PLY: PARSE DEBUG END
calc >
```

Parse Table generated at parser.out

```
Created by PLY version 3.2 (http://www.dabeaz.com/ply)

Grammar

Rule 0     S' -> statement
Rule 1     statement -> NAME = expression
Rule 2     statement -> expression
Rule 3     expression -> expression + expression
Rule 4     expression -> expression - expression
Rule 5     expression -> expression * expression
Rule 6     expression -> expression / expression
Rule 7     expression -> - expression
Rule 8     expression -> ( expression )
Rule 9     expression -> NUMBER
Rule 10    expression -> NAME

Terminals, with rules where they appear

(                    : 8
)                    : 8
*                    : 5
+                    : 3
-                    : 4 7
/                    : 6
=                    : 1
NAME                 : 1 10
NUMBER               : 9
error                : 

Nonterminals, with rules where they appear

expression           : 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 8
statement            : 0

Parsing method: LALR

state 0

    (0) S' -> . statement
    (1) statement -> . NAME = expression
    (2) statement -> . expression
    (3) expression -> . expression + expression
    (4) expression -> . expression - expression
    (5) expression -> . expression * expression
    (6) expression -> . expression / expression
    (7) expression -> . - expression
    (8) expression -> . ( expression )
    (9) expression -> . NUMBER
    (10) expression -> . NAME

    NAME            shift and go to state 1
    -               shift and go to state 2
    (               shift and go to state 5
    NUMBER          shift and go to state 3

    expression                     shift and go to state 6
    statement                      shift and go to state 4

state 1

    (1) statement -> NAME . = expression
    (10) expression -> NAME .

    =               shift and go to state 7
    +               reduce using rule 10 (expression -> NAME .)
    -               reduce using rule 10 (expression -> NAME .)
    *               reduce using rule 10 (expression -> NAME .)
    /               reduce using rule 10 (expression -> NAME .)
    $end            reduce using rule 10 (expression -> NAME .)


state 2

    (7) expression -> - . expression
    (3) expression -> . expression + expression
    (4) expression -> . expression - expression
    (5) expression -> . expression * expression
    (6) expression -> . expression / expression
    (7) expression -> . - expression
    (8) expression -> . ( expression )
    (9) expression -> . NUMBER
    (10) expression -> . NAME

    -               shift and go to state 2
    (               shift and go to state 5
    NUMBER          shift and go to state 3
    NAME            shift and go to state 8

    expression                     shift and go to state 9

state 3

    (9) expression -> NUMBER .

    +               reduce using rule 9 (expression -> NUMBER .)
    -               reduce using rule 9 (expression -> NUMBER .)
    *               reduce using rule 9 (expression -> NUMBER .)
    /               reduce using rule 9 (expression -> NUMBER .)
    $end            reduce using rule 9 (expression -> NUMBER .)
    )               reduce using rule 9 (expression -> NUMBER .)


state 4

    (0) S' -> statement .



state 5

    (8) expression -> ( . expression )
    (3) expression -> . expression + expression
    (4) expression -> . expression - expression
    (5) expression -> . expression * expression
    (6) expression -> . expression / expression
    (7) expression -> . - expression
    (8) expression -> . ( expression )
    (9) expression -> . NUMBER
    (10) expression -> . NAME

    -               shift and go to state 2
    (               shift and go to state 5
    NUMBER          shift and go to state 3
    NAME            shift and go to state 8

    expression                     shift and go to state 10

state 6

    (2) statement -> expression .
    (3) expression -> expression . + expression
    (4) expression -> expression . - expression
    (5) expression -> expression . * expression
    (6) expression -> expression . / expression

    $end            reduce using rule 2 (statement -> expression .)
    +               shift and go to state 12
    -               shift and go to state 11
    *               shift and go to state 13
    /               shift and go to state 14


state 7

    (1) statement -> NAME = . expression
    (3) expression -> . expression + expression
    (4) expression -> . expression - expression
    (5) expression -> . expression * expression
    (6) expression -> . expression / expression
    (7) expression -> . - expression
    (8) expression -> . ( expression )
    (9) expression -> . NUMBER
    (10) expression -> . NAME

    -               shift and go to state 2
    (               shift and go to state 5
    NUMBER          shift and go to state 3
    NAME            shift and go to state 8

    expression                     shift and go to state 15

state 8

    (10) expression -> NAME .

    +               reduce using rule 10 (expression -> NAME .)
    -               reduce using rule 10 (expression -> NAME .)
    *               reduce using rule 10 (expression -> NAME .)
    /               reduce using rule 10 (expression -> NAME .)
    $end            reduce using rule 10 (expression -> NAME .)
    )               reduce using rule 10 (expression -> NAME .)


state 9

    (7) expression -> - expression .
    (3) expression -> expression . + expression
    (4) expression -> expression . - expression
    (5) expression -> expression . * expression
    (6) expression -> expression . / expression

    +               reduce using rule 7 (expression -> - expression .)
    -               reduce using rule 7 (expression -> - expression .)
    *               reduce using rule 7 (expression -> - expression .)
    /               reduce using rule 7 (expression -> - expression .)
    $end            reduce using rule 7 (expression -> - expression .)
    )               reduce using rule 7 (expression -> - expression .)

  ! +               [ shift and go to state 12 ]
  ! -               [ shift and go to state 11 ]
  ! *               [ shift and go to state 13 ]
  ! /               [ shift and go to state 14 ]


state 10

    (8) expression -> ( expression . )
    (3) expression -> expression . + expression
    (4) expression -> expression . - expression
    (5) expression -> expression . * expression
    (6) expression -> expression . / expression

    )               shift and go to state 16
    +               shift and go to state 12
    -               shift and go to state 11
    *               shift and go to state 13
    /               shift and go to state 14


state 11

    (4) expression -> expression - . expression
    (3) expression -> . expression + expression
    (4) expression -> . expression - expression
    (5) expression -> . expression * expression
    (6) expression -> . expression / expression
    (7) expression -> . - expression
    (8) expression -> . ( expression )
    (9) expression -> . NUMBER
    (10) expression -> . NAME

    -               shift and go to state 2
    (               shift and go to state 5
    NUMBER          shift and go to state 3
    NAME            shift and go to state 8

    expression                     shift and go to state 17

state 12

    (3) expression -> expression + . expression
    (3) expression -> . expression + expression
    (4) expression -> . expression - expression
    (5) expression -> . expression * expression
    (6) expression -> . expression / expression
    (7) expression -> . - expression
    (8) expression -> . ( expression )
    (9) expression -> . NUMBER
    (10) expression -> . NAME

    -               shift and go to state 2
    (               shift and go to state 5
    NUMBER          shift and go to state 3
    NAME            shift and go to state 8

    expression                     shift and go to state 18

state 13

    (5) expression -> expression * . expression
    (3) expression -> . expression + expression
    (4) expression -> . expression - expression
    (5) expression -> . expression * expression
    (6) expression -> . expression / expression
    (7) expression -> . - expression
    (8) expression -> . ( expression )
    (9) expression -> . NUMBER
    (10) expression -> . NAME

    -               shift and go to state 2
    (               shift and go to state 5
    NUMBER          shift and go to state 3
    NAME            shift and go to state 8

    expression                     shift and go to state 19

state 14

    (6) expression -> expression / . expression
    (3) expression -> . expression + expression
    (4) expression -> . expression - expression
    (5) expression -> . expression * expression
    (6) expression -> . expression / expression
    (7) expression -> . - expression
    (8) expression -> . ( expression )
    (9) expression -> . NUMBER
    (10) expression -> . NAME

    -               shift and go to state 2
    (               shift and go to state 5
    NUMBER          shift and go to state 3
    NAME            shift and go to state 8

    expression                     shift and go to state 20

state 15

    (1) statement -> NAME = expression .
    (3) expression -> expression . + expression
    (4) expression -> expression . - expression
    (5) expression -> expression . * expression
    (6) expression -> expression . / expression

    $end            reduce using rule 1 (statement -> NAME = expression .)
    +               shift and go to state 12
    -               shift and go to state 11
    *               shift and go to state 13
    /               shift and go to state 14


state 16

    (8) expression -> ( expression ) .

    +               reduce using rule 8 (expression -> ( expression ) .)
    -               reduce using rule 8 (expression -> ( expression ) .)
    *               reduce using rule 8 (expression -> ( expression ) .)
    /               reduce using rule 8 (expression -> ( expression ) .)
    $end            reduce using rule 8 (expression -> ( expression ) .)
    )               reduce using rule 8 (expression -> ( expression ) .)


state 17

    (4) expression -> expression - expression .
    (3) expression -> expression . + expression
    (4) expression -> expression . - expression
    (5) expression -> expression . * expression
    (6) expression -> expression . / expression

    +               reduce using rule 4 (expression -> expression - expression .)
    -               reduce using rule 4 (expression -> expression - expression .)
    $end            reduce using rule 4 (expression -> expression - expression .)
    )               reduce using rule 4 (expression -> expression - expression .)
    *               shift and go to state 13
    /               shift and go to state 14

  ! *               [ reduce using rule 4 (expression -> expression - expression .) ]
  ! /               [ reduce using rule 4 (expression -> expression - expression .) ]
  ! +               [ shift and go to state 12 ]
  ! -               [ shift and go to state 11 ]


state 18

    (3) expression -> expression + expression .
    (3) expression -> expression . + expression
    (4) expression -> expression . - expression
    (5) expression -> expression . * expression
    (6) expression -> expression . / expression

    +               reduce using rule 3 (expression -> expression + expression .)
    -               reduce using rule 3 (expression -> expression + expression .)
    $end            reduce using rule 3 (expression -> expression + expression .)
    )               reduce using rule 3 (expression -> expression + expression .)
    *               shift and go to state 13
    /               shift and go to state 14

  ! *               [ reduce using rule 3 (expression -> expression + expression .) ]
  ! /               [ reduce using rule 3 (expression -> expression + expression .) ]
  ! +               [ shift and go to state 12 ]
  ! -               [ shift and go to state 11 ]


state 19

    (5) expression -> expression * expression .
    (3) expression -> expression . + expression
    (4) expression -> expression . - expression
    (5) expression -> expression . * expression
    (6) expression -> expression . / expression

    +               reduce using rule 5 (expression -> expression * expression .)
    -               reduce using rule 5 (expression -> expression * expression .)
    *               reduce using rule 5 (expression -> expression * expression .)
    /               reduce using rule 5 (expression -> expression * expression .)
    $end            reduce using rule 5 (expression -> expression * expression .)
    )               reduce using rule 5 (expression -> expression * expression .)

  ! +               [ shift and go to state 12 ]
  ! -               [ shift and go to state 11 ]
  ! *               [ shift and go to state 13 ]
  ! /               [ shift and go to state 14 ]


state 20

    (6) expression -> expression / expression .
    (3) expression -> expression . + expression
    (4) expression -> expression . - expression
    (5) expression -> expression . * expression
    (6) expression -> expression . / expression

    +               reduce using rule 6 (expression -> expression / expression .)
    -               reduce using rule 6 (expression -> expression / expression .)
    *               reduce using rule 6 (expression -> expression / expression .)
    /               reduce using rule 6 (expression -> expression / expression .)
    $end            reduce using rule 6 (expression -> expression / expression .)
    )               reduce using rule 6 (expression -> expression / expression .)

  ! +               [ shift and go to state 12 ]
  ! -               [ shift and go to state 11 ]
  ! *               [ shift and go to state 13 ]
  ! /               [ shift and go to state 14 ]
```

Comment: this is very nice! thanks! if no other answers get posted in a day, you win.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about its debugging features, but I've heard good things about PyParsing.

http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 2):

I know the bounty has already been claimed, but here is an equivalent parser written in pyparsing (plus support for function calls with zero or more comma-delimted arguments):

```
from pyparsing import *

LPAR, RPAR = map(Suppress,"()")
EQ = Literal("=")
name = Word(alphas, alphanums+"_").setName("name")
number = Word(nums).setName("number")

expr = Forward()
operand = Optional('-') + (Group(name + LPAR + 
                                  Group(Optional(delimitedList(expr))) +
                                  RPAR) |
                           name | 
                           number | 
                           Group(LPAR + expr + RPAR))
binop = oneOf("+ - * / **")
expr << (Group(operand + OneOrMore(binop + operand)) | operand)

assignment = name + EQ + expr
statement = assignment | expr
```

This test code runs the parser through its basic paces:

```
tests = """\
    sin(pi/2)
    y = mx+b
    E = mc ** 2
    F = m*a
    x = x0 + v*t +a*t*t/2
    1 - sqrt(sin(t)**2 + cos(t)**2)""".splitlines()

for t in tests:
    print t.strip()
    print statement.parseString(t).asList()
    print
```

Gives this output:

```
sin(pi/2)
[['sin', [['pi', '/', '2']]]]

y = mx+b
['y', '=', ['mx', '+', 'b']]

E = mc ** 2
['E', '=', ['mc', '**', '2']]

F = m*a
['F', '=', ['m', '*', 'a']]

x = x0 + v*t +a*t*t/2
['x', '=', ['x0', '+', 'v', '*', 't', '+', 'a', '*', 't', '*', 't', '/', '2']]

1 - sqrt(sin(t)**2 + cos(t)**2)
[['1', '-', ['sqrt', [[['sin', ['t']], '**', '2', '+', ['cos', ['t']], '**', '2']]]]]
```

For debugging, we add this code:

```
# enable debugging for name and number expressions
name.setDebug()
number.setDebug()
```

And now we reparse the first test (displaying the input string and a simple column ruler):

```
t = tests[0]
print ("1234567890"*10)[:len(t)]
print t
statement.parseString(t)
print
```

Giving this output:

```
1234567890123
    sin(pi/2)
Match name at loc 4(1,5)
Matched name -> ['sin']
Match name at loc 4(1,5)
Matched name -> ['sin']
Match name at loc 8(1,9)
Matched name -> ['pi']
Match name at loc 8(1,9)
Matched name -> ['pi']
Match name at loc 11(1,12)
Exception raised:Expected name (at char 11), (line:1, col:12)
Match name at loc 11(1,12)
Exception raised:Expected name (at char 11), (line:1, col:12)
Match number at loc 11(1,12)
Matched number -> ['2']
Match name at loc 4(1,5)
Matched name -> ['sin']
Match name at loc 8(1,9)
Matched name -> ['pi']
Match name at loc 8(1,9)
Matched name -> ['pi']
Match name at loc 11(1,12)
Exception raised:Expected name (at char 11), (line:1, col:12)
Match name at loc 11(1,12)
Exception raised:Expected name (at char 11), (line:1, col:12)
Match number at loc 11(1,12)
Matched number -> ['2']
```

Pyparsing also supports packrat parsing, a sort of parse-time memoization (read more about packratting [here](http://pyparsing-public.wikispaces.com/FAQs#toc3)).  Here is the same parsing sequence, but with packrat enabled:

```
same parse, but with packrat parsing enabled
1234567890123
    sin(pi/2)
Match name at loc 4(1,5)
Matched name -> ['sin']
Match name at loc 8(1,9)
Matched name -> ['pi']
Match name at loc 8(1,9)
Matched name -> ['pi']
Match name at loc 11(1,12)
Exception raised:Expected name (at char 11), (line:1, col:12)
Match name at loc 11(1,12)
Exception raised:Expected name (at char 11), (line:1, col:12)
Match number at loc 11(1,12)
Matched number -> ['2']
```

This was an interesting exercise, and helpful to me to see debugging features from other parser libraries.

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR above has the advantage to generate human readable and understandable code,
since it is (a very sophisticated and powerful) top-down parser,
so you can step through it with a regular debugger
and see what it *really* is doing.

That's why it is my parser generator of choice.

Bottom up parser generators like PLY have the disadvantage
that for larger grammars it is almost impossible to understand
what the debugging output really means and why the
parsing table is like it is.

Answer (score 0):

Python wiki has a [list](http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing) of Language Parsers written in Python.

Comment: I know that. This isn't really helping.

Comment: @Geo: Why the downvote (assuming it was you)?  How could cartman have known you'd already seen the list?

Comment: The question was pretty specific, I think. I asked for parser generators that have good debugging features. He posted a list, not something specific.

Comment: 3rd party here hadn't seen the list and is glad to see it mentioned. May have been better as a comment though.